# Storing spreadsheet-type data from a file to a data structure in Java

Tags: java, swing, javafx, data-structures, file-io

I have a spreadsheet-type data file(tab-delimited .txt) which needs to be read by the Java program and store the values in a data structure. This data represents the shortest path between two cities and filled with a dash (-) if the path doesn't exist. Which data structure would serve a good purpose into storing these values for further comparisons into the program; mainly for a searching algorithm? Furthermore, I would like to print the cities listed in the first column in a simple GUI as a drop-down button which allows the user to choose a city? Only the line of code to print the cities out by extracting out would be good.
And, here's how the data-file looks:

```
            Port Col    Minn    Cali    Flo
Portland    -   30  -   22  -
Colorado    15  17  5   -   -
Minnesota   11  15  22  13  -
California  8   -   9   -   -
Florida     11  -   -   22  -
```

Since this is a tab-delimited .txt file, it doesn't look perfect.

Comment: What is the data going to be used for?  It may be easiest to keep it as Strings if you're just printing it, but if you're using it internally an array or List may help

Comment: I would consider something like a `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>`; you might want to wrap that in your own class to make it easier to use. But, as stated, it depends on how you are going to use it.

Comment: @James_D can you elaborate briefly on your idea?

Comment: The keys for the "outer" map would be the city names, and the value would be a map  from each city to the corresponding distance. So, e.g. `Map<String, Double> portlandDists = new HashMap<>();`, `portlandDists.put("Colorado", 30.0);`, `portlandDists.put("California", 22);`, `distances.put("Portland", portlandDists)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For reading the file I would rather rename it to .csv and use one of standard csv readers. You can usually configure them to use other delimiters, including tabs.
This will give you some spreadsheet-like structure in memory. You will be able to get list of headers (cities) and map-like structure with distances for each city.

This approach is bit less coding and more reading, but this is what real job often ends up being like, so it's a good practice if you can handle it.

example CSV libraries:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: no need to rename anything ... it's the storage format that matters not the file extension ...

Comment: You're right. Most libraries don't care about the extension. I just meant to be clear that I want to treat the file as csv-like data format.